# Rest application header based vs path based service routing

Tags: rest, api, api-design, web-api, routing

i have a rest API that is a front end to a more complex SOAP based service. The soap based service uses extended(custom) WSA-addressing headers in order to perform its routing. The extension of the WSA-Addressing adds two header parameters country and city for example. Since the routing elements are mandatory I need to pass them in some form to the REST API and then use them on the SOAP client in order to get the routing right. I have two options with regards of the REST API:

1. Pass them as HTTP headers
2. Pass them as path parameters.
   Lets say that for example the two routing parameters are land and city and my REST resource ID is 123456.

them my GET will look like:

```
getResource/country/city/123456
```

If I use headers then it will be:

```
getResourfce/123456
```

It should be noted that the ID alone is uniquly identifying a resource , so the country and city are for routing only.

If I was using SOAP there would have been no question that I will use HEADERs. What is the situation when REST is used with regards of routing.

What is the proper way of expressing this parameters ? Headers or path elements ?

Comment: Using the REST paradigm you access resources. The  `path` to the resource is typically `$collection/$specific?$filter`, e.g. `/products/shoes?brand=Nike`.

Comment: @ThomasJunk thanks for the answer. But I have read that the requestParameters should be optional and not mandatory. In my case though country and city are mandatory. Is this not changing the things ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with required query string parameters. If the consumer doesn't pass them then you return a 400 indicating that `country` and `city` are required.

Comment: @DanWilson is using headers bad idea ? If yes why ?

Comment: @DanWilson why not path parameters?

Comment: Headers would work just as well, although query string parameters seem more common in my experience. There are general REST guidelines but ultimately you should design your API based on what you think your consumers will expect and understand, and then document it well.

Comment: I wouldn't prefer path parts for the reason you mentioned, namely that an ID can uniquely identify a resource.

Comment: @Dan Wilson hei what if a key can exist only in one combination Of country city. Because Of the partitioning. Which maybe tommorrow can be country brand instead Of country city.

Comment: When you say `using SOAP there would have been no question that I will use HEADER` are you perhaps confusing envelop message headers with HTTP headers? because they are nothing alike.

Comment: `is using headers bad idea? If yes why ?` Because it's the wrong tool for solving the wrong problem. Just because you can do that it doesn't mean you have to. Otherwise, why using request parameters at all?

Comment: @Laiv what if one endpoint can serve multiplum countries and the data the key belongs to does not actualy belong to the country Of the endpoint? Example key=1234 belongs for order issued in sweden, therefore original country is set to sweden, but the service endpoint in norway serves both sweden and norway durin Hugh volume hours. This is example.

Comment: @Laiv i think query parameter for such example, it does not look right for me.

Comment: Why? Don't think in "parameters" think in "IDS". A complete URI must be seen as a meaningless ID. Think also in the network topology, you will never know if your headers are going to be blocked, ignored or cause collision somewhere in the way up to your endpoint. I might be wrong, but I got the feeling you are too biased by the SOAP implementation of the service you are hiding. Forget what would you do in SOAP, the point of your REST endpoint is to make clients agnostic to all that complexity.

Comment: @Laiv you may be right about my bias, I have significantly more experience with soap than rest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It should be noted that the ID alone is uniquly identifying a resource , so the country and city are for routing only.

Sounds like the ID alone doesn't actually uniquely identify the resource, since if the underlying SOAP service requires them to find the resource and only having the ID can't identify the resource, they are in fact required to identify the resource.

Having IDs that are not shared across resources is not the same thing as the ID itself being able to uniquely identify a resource.

Even if `/Canada/Toronto/12345` and `/Ireland/Dublin/12345` will never happen because the IDs are not shared you still need this country and city information to get the correct resource.

So I would put them in the URL.

Don't put them in the header. This information has nothing to do with the HTTP transport level.

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: "Don't put them in the header. This information has nothing to do with the HTTP transport level." this is a non-sequitur.

Comment: Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. The HTTP header is concerned with facilitating the state transfer of the resource, it doesn't and shouldn't care about specific business logic of the resource (ie the different states of the specific resource).

Comment: Note that in HTTP, some headers are used to communicate redirection and forwarding. It's not totally out of place what the OP is asking. It's just a little bit forced because it implies something else. A router, not a mere http server.

Comment: That is quite different to using the header to construct the URI though, particularly when the construction in the header itself is resource specific (ie only done for certain types of resources)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it's up to you to decide, both options are possible.

At first I didn't like the header approach but then I found two examples of header usage in RESTful services that make it look sensible:

- `Authorization:` headers are used to control access rights to resources, including possibly different visibility of fields.
- `Accept:` headers can be used to select the presentation of resources, i.e. the same resource could be presented as JSON, XML, or HTML data.

However, if each resource is only accessible with one specific country/city combination and the client needs to know that `usa/new_york` is needed for 11112222 but `spain/madrid` for 11112233, these should go into the path. Header values are not part of a URI, and remembering or finding out which country and city need to be passed in the request for a specific resource should not be the client's responsibility.

Comment: In my case one ID althought completly unique can exist only in one combination Of city, country.

Comment: What if partitioning change tomorrow to country Brand f.ex. Isnt IT a bit risky to build your uri around partitioning which may not exist tomorrow. Probably IT is pretty fixed but still.

Comment: Whether you put partitioning info into header or path doesn't matter in that situation. The client will have a non-working link. If you put routing in the path, you could handle this with a HTTP 301 response. How would you handle outdated header values?

Answer (score -1):

There is absolutely noting wrong about passing parameters in headers.  Any decent REST framework will support it.  It's not typically a first choice but there is one situation where you definitely [should pass your parameters in headers](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#sensitive-information-in-http-requests):

> RESTful web services should be careful to prevent leaking credentials. Passwords, security tokens, and API keys should not appear in the URL, as this can be captured in web server logs, which makes them intrinsically valuable.
>
> - In POST/PUT requests sensitive data should be transferred in the request body or request headers.
> - In GET requests sensitive data should be transferred in an HTTP Header.

While the above refers directly to security data, the same logic would apply to any other kind of sensitive information e.g. credit card numbers.

Comment: Authentication is different to resource specific content information. The HTTP header deals with facilitating the state transfer of resources. It doesn't care what type of resource. The resource itself (either the body or its URI) is concerned with the specifics of the resource. So this is really apples and oranges. Putting resource content type logic in the HTTP header is a REST anti-pattern and will make your API brittle and confusing to clients

Comment: @CormacMulhall Feel free to ignore the OWASP recommendations at your own peril.

Comment: @CormacMulhall Wait, are you saying you don't use Accept and Content headers?  That's bonkers.

Comment: No, I'm saying Accept and Content headers don't care about the specific of the resource being transferred, they just take a Content Type which can be any string. It is up to the client and server to figure out the specific of that content type, not the HTTP protocol. Changing the Header based on the specific content type of the resource you are transferring state for is a recipe for long term problems maintaining your API and is a REST anti-pattern since the point of REST is that the HTTP protocol doesn't care about the specifics of the resource

Comment: @CormacMulhall I really don't know what that has to do with the subject here.  If you are passing sensitive parameters, the security recommendation is that they not be in the URI.  If you have content in the request, you can opt to put the sensitive parameter there.  If you are doing a GET, you don't really have that option.  I personally dislike the idea of turning a GET into a POST or PUT but some opt for that instead of using the headers.  BTW custom headers are absolutely fine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Comment: The OWASP recommendations don't say put any params you like in the header they say put credentials in the header. The original question doesn't have anything to do with authentication or passing of credentials. But you also shouldn't have an authentication system that has a HTTP authentication header specific to the particular resource being accessed.

Comment: @CormacMulhall The OWASP doesn't say you can use and header you like, the RFCs do.  The point of the OWASP recommendation is that you can leak sensitive information.  If you understand why, it should be obvious that it applies to anything sensitive as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @CormacMulhall You seem to be having a conversation with yourself.  None of what you are saying is relevant or mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I don't know where the concern about sensitive information came from, but you should not be uniquely identifying your resource based on header information in the first place so it is a moot point, whether these are in the secure or not. A URL that is "myapi.com/my_resources/[check-the-header]" is wrong whether you are going to the header for secure params or not.

Comment: @CormacMulhall I'll give a specific example.  I am given a requirement for a service to retrieve data about a person based on an ID that is deemed sensitive information.  Where do I put that id in a GET request?

Comment: @CormacMulhall "I don't know where the concern about sensitive information came from" It comes from the reality that we live in. e.g. identifying information is often sensitive.

Comment: "Where do I put that id in a GET request?" In the URL. If the ID is sensitive information you don't stick it into the header, you change it to use a non-sensitive URL. Sticking it into the header is wrong on multiple levels.

Comment: @CormacMulhall "In the URL. If the ID is sensitive information you don't stick it into the header, you change it to use a non-sensitive URL." In the URL?  So you don't understand the problem with that or you don't care?  What's a 'non-sensitive URL'?

Comment: There are many good ways to identify a resource without leaking sensitive information about that resource (for example using a one way hash). Simply sticking the sensitive information in the header is not one of them.

Comment: @CormacMulhall Says who, you?  I'm done but here's [some reading](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Best-Practices-for-Parameters-and-Query-String-Usage/) you can explore:"If such a parameter should go into a custom header or the query string is mostly a question of developer experience.

The HTTP specification states that header fields are kinda like function parameters, so they are indeed thought of as the parameters we want to use, but ..."

Comment: @CormacMulhall My copy is a little dated but in ["RESTful Web Services"](https://www.amazon.com/RESTful-Web-Services-Leonard-Richardson/dp/0596529260) This text is in the intro to Appendix C which is about headers: "So long as client and server agree on what the headers mean, *you can send any information you like* along with a request of response"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102326/discussion-between-cormac-mulhall-and-jimmyjames).